# Showing "No mail Accounts",Where the mail account is configured in Account

Tags: ios, iphone, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

[image]

Showing “No Mail Account” alert when trying to call a mail controller.I configured the mail account in my iPad, also I am able send mail using apple email client. But when I am trying to send mail using my application the above alert is  displayed. (I have a mail sending option in apps contact us page, implemented using `MFMailComposeViewController`).

What causes the problem ?

Comment: Show the code plz

Comment: Actually,Normally the I am able to send email from the contaus page of application.I got this issue only once .So I think there is no mistake in my code,The code is correctly working.But unfortunately I got this alert once.Any one have any idea ?